# How to solve this question in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,A)$ be a measure space.
Let $C\neq\emptyset \subseteq{P(X)}$

$p: P(X)\to {0,1}$ that satisfy

$p(\emptyset)=1$

$p(c)=1$ $\forall c\in{C}$

if $p(a)=1$ then $p(a^c)=1$

If $p(a_n)=1$ $\forall n\in{N}$ then $p(\cup_{n\in{N}} a_n) \in =1$.

Show that $p(c)=1$ $\forall$ $c\in{A(C)}$.

$A(c)$ is the $\sigma$ algebra generated by $c$.

Edited answer to the question:
Define $B={c\in{C} : p(c)=1}$.

The set $B$ is a $\sigma$ algebra (from the conditions above).
Moreover, $C\subset{B}$ (since $\forall c\in{C}\subset{A(C)} p(c)=1$ ).
We see that $B$ is a sigma algebra that includes $C$ l, on the other side $A(C)$ is the minimal sigma algebra that includes $C$, thus $C\subset{A(C)}\subset{B}$ leading to the ordered result.

- The $A(C)$ is the intersection of all the sigma algebra that include $C$, and it's the minimal one of those.

Comment: $\{c \in A(C): p(c)=1\}$ is a sigma algebra by the given conditions. It also contains $C$. Since $A(C)$ is the smallest such sigma algebra we get $A(C) \subseteq \{c \in A(C): p(c)=1\}$. So $p(c)=1$  for all $c \in A(C)$.

Comment: Thanks! I Edited my post